# ImageMagick: GIF animation with transparent background

Tags: animation, imagemagick, transparency, animated-gif, imagemagick-convert

This is my first post here and I will try to be concise and accurate in my explanation.

I am trying to create a very simple GIF animation for my web site, I am completely new in this world since I started playing around with ImageMagick yesterday, and I am having serious problems to get the result I want. The animation consists of only 2 frames that swap infinitely. Here you can see the [basic animation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ux7z5m1z7z3y7qt/logo_anim_basic.gif?dl=0).

As you can see, the animation consists of a couple of characters, that change from frame to frame, on a **transparent background**. No problem so far. The problem is that *I want the transition from one frame to the other to be **as smooth as possible***, not only a basic switch. I found the way to define this kind of transition on the documentation. However, **this command is unable to create the animation** I need because of the background transparency since **it breaks the transparency during the transition** and it messes it up a lot! If I change the background color to, let's say, black everything works as expected... Here you can find the animation on a [transparent background](https://www.dropbox.com/s/iywjdbudx55jkrl/logo_anim_11.gif?dl=0).

These are the commands I used:

```
convert logo_1.png logo_3.png -morph 15 -set delay 10   \( -clone 0 -set delay 240 \) -swap 0 +delete \
      \( +clone   -set delay 240 \) +swap   +delete \
      -duplicate 1,-2-1  logo_anim_9.gif
convert -alpha Set logo_1.png logo_3.png -morph 15 -set delay 10   \( -clone 0 -set delay 240 \) -swap 0 +delete \
      \( +clone   -set delay 240 \) +swap   +delete \
      -duplicate 1,-2-1  logo_anim_11.gif
```

However, the `-alpha Set` did nothin regarding the transparent background...

I will be very grateful if someone can give me a hand with this since I'm very unexperienced with the use of this software and I would like to get the animation with the soft transition with a transparent background.

Many thanks in advance.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

Got to go to bed, and I haven't cracked it yet, however the following may help you work it out.

**Hint 1**

This command is handy for debugging animations:

```
identify -format "Scene:%s Time:%T Geom:%g Dispose:%D\n" log*9*

Scene:0 Time:40 Geom:300x240+0+0 Dispose:Previous
Scene:1 Time:40 Geom:300x240+0+0 Dispose:Previous
Scene:2 Time:40 Geom:300x240+0+0 Dispose:Previous
Scene:3 Time:40 Geom:300x240+0+0 Dispose:Previous
Scene:4 Time:40 Geom:300x240+0+0 Dispose:Previous
Scene:5 Time:40 Geom:300x240+0+0 Dispose:Previous
Scene:6 Time:40 Geom:300x240+0+0 Dispose:Previous
Scene:7 Time:40 Geom:300x240+0+0 Dispose:Previous
Scene:8 Time:40 Geom:300x240+0+0 Dispose:Previous
Scene:9 Time:40 Geom:300x240+0+0 Dispose:Previous
Scene:10 Time:40 Geom:300x240+0+0 Dispose:Previous
Scene:11 Time:40 Geom:300x240+0+0 Dispose:Previous
Scene:12 Time:40 Geom:300x240+0+0 Dispose:Previous
Scene:13 Time:40 Geom:300x240+0+0 Dispose:Previous
Scene:14 Time:40 Geom:300x240+0+0 Dispose:Previous
Scene:15 Time:40 Geom:300x240+0+0 Dispose:Previous
Scene:16 Time:40 Geom:300x240+0+0 Dispose:Previous
Scene:17 Time:40 Geom:300x240+0+0 Dispose:Previous
Scene:18 Time:40 Geom:300x240+0+0 Dispose:Previous
Scene:19 Time:40 Geom:300x240+0+0 Dispose:Previous
Scene:20 Time:40 Geom:300x240+0+0 Dispose:Previous
```

**Hint 2**

Your initial images that were generated by `-morph` look wrong. You can see them side-by-side, using `+append` like this:

```
convert logo_1.png logo_3.png -morph 15 +append result.png
```

[image]

I tried generating them manually with this:

```
#!/bin/bash -xv
rm frame-*png
f=0
for p in $(seq 0 5 100); do
   echo Percentage: $p
   name=$(printf "frame-%02d.png" $f)
   convert logo_1.png logo_3.png -compose blend -define compose:args=$p -composite $name
   ((f++))
done
convert frame-*png +append result.png
```

[image]

And they are just above this line but you can't see them :-)

**Hint 3**

Try experimenting with `-dispose`. You can see the available options with:

```
identify -list dispose

Undefined
Background
None
Previous
0
1
2
3
```

So, try:

```
convert -dispose previous ...
```

Comment: Many thanks @Mark for your very valuable help! The script you provided has helped me a lot! However, the final result I get after creating the animation still has a bad behavior [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e2y0viuuor5y4y3/logo-magic.gif?dl=0) you can see what I am talking about! I think it has something to do with the transparency...

To create the animation I added the following line to the end of your script `convert -delay 10 -dispose previous frame-*png  logo-magic.gif` but still something may be missing because the final result is not the one I am looking for...

Comment: However, as I said, your script has been really useful to me since I used it in order to get another animation instead. I readapted the script to get a rotation animation with [this script](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/3Drotate/index.php), and [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6pl75c17yvjojp5/logo-rotated.gif?dl=0) you can see the result. As you can see, in this case the animation is created successfully, without any problem dealing with transparency. Why can I not get the correct result with the first animation if the process is the same?